# How to animate a very accurate cylinder deformation?

Tags: surface-deform

I'm very, very new to Blender (I'm not yet using plugins). I've been tasked to learn 3D animation to show the riveting process of the blind inserts for the company I work for.

To achieve this, I'm trying to deform a cylinder that I shaped with a bunch of boolean objects. I then added a lot of geometry to the lower (threadless) part that I'm trying to deform.

[image: image of blind insert object]

I tried deforming this part of the object with curves and lattice (both straight and bent with simple deform), however I never get a satisfying result. In an ideal world the material should fold over itself like it does in the real world and be taken from the top, so that the tread moves closer to the base part of the insert.

[image: geometry of blind insert model with mo][image: deformation with magically added material]

It's very important to control the exact deformation of the rivet, as that is one of the major selling points of our blind inserts.

Our competition does it like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RM-9JbRbKqE, which would be ideal to recreate. The scene I'm focusing on right now is in seconds 21-24.

I'd be very thankful for any help or suggestions on personal blender lessons!

Comment: i would try it with shapekeys and proportional editing in edit mode

Comment: so with 2 mins effort you could get this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5wuE.gif -> just a cylinder with a lot of subdivisions and then shape keys deformed with proportional editing. For demo i just added a boolean modifier to the cylinder so that it is cut in the middle.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! Shape keys seems to be what I was looking for! 

How did you get the cylinder to compress outward instead of onto itself? Did you move every single geo point or is there some way to make Blender move all of the walls outward when compressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after subdividing your cylinder, add shape keys, go to edit mode and toggle x ray, in front view select your vertices, toggle proportional editing and move as you like it. Add solidify modifier.

[image]

[image]

after that i moved all vertices above and under the bulge a bit down and up so that it looks like it would shorten in z direction. (this isn't shown in the gifs)

Comment: Chris, thank you so much! I've understood now and it's the right idea.

Comment: i am glad it helped you. pls click on the checkmark left of my answer, if my answer helped, thx!